# WCF serialize exception

Tags: wcf

I have a type MyParameter that i pass as a parameter to a wcf service

```
[Serializable]
public class MyParameter : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Mytype { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        XElement e = XElement.Parse(reader.ReadOuterXml());
        IEnumerable<XElement> i = e.Elements();
        List<XElement> l = new List<XElement>(i);
        Name = l[0].Name.ToString();
        Value = l[0].Value.ToString();
        Mytype = l[0].Attribute("type").Value.ToString();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(Name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi:type", Mytype);
        writer.WriteValue(Value);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

the service contract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOperation
{
[OperationContract]
void Operation(List<Data> list);
```

}

where data defines a  data contract

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<MyParameter> Parameters{ get; set; }
}
```

when i run the service and test it 
i get rhe exception in readXml of MyParameter
"the prefix xsi is not defined"
xsi should define the namespace "http://w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance"

How do I fix the problem?

I am very new to this so a sample code will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly tell the XmlWriter what xsi maps to. Try this instead:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "type", "http://w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance", MyType);
```

Comment: i dont understand can you please explain

Comment: You don't understand what? It's simple, you're assuming that the XmlWriter somehow magically knows what the xsi prefix maps to. It doesn't , so you have to tell it explicitly.

Just replace the line where you write the xsi:type attribute with what I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the IXmlSerializable. WCF tries to handle the serialization in the background without bothering you about it.

It looks like you may be missing a couple attributes on your DataContract object. Try this instead:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data {

[DataMember]
public string Name { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public List<string> Parameters { get; set; }

}
```

The [DataMember] attribute marks which properties you want WCF to automatically serialize for you.